# Importing a dynamic web project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets

I have a problem while importing the Dynamic web application project(implemented in jdk 6 and Tomcat 6) in Eclipse to my PC which has jdk 7 and Tomcat 7  with Eclipse Galileo.. Eclipse is not showing any error, but i cant run the .jsp files as the 'run on server' option is not highlighted, instead its showing 'run configuration'

```
How can i solve this..?
```

Comment: Have you verified that your project is linked to the right server?

Comment: How can i check it.. ACTUALLY I am new to Eclipse

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse for web development but I think this link can help you : http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftjtargetserver.html

Comment: did you configure any server?

Comment: I have configured Apache Tomcat 7.0